# Restoring partitioned table data causes error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have partitioned tables and dumped it with `pg_dump`

```
pg_dump \
    --dbname "${DBNAME}" \
    --table 'log_*' \
    --format "directory" \
    --file ./backup \
    --jobs "${JOBS}" \
    --username "${USERNAME}"
```

Table is named `log` and its partitioned tables are `log_${year}_${month}`, e.g. `log_2023_01`, `log_2023_02`.

But on restoring in into newly created DB which only has main table `log`,

```
pg_restore --dbname postgres --username ${USERNAME} .
```

It spits error

```
pg_restore: from TOC entry 3201; 1259 17268 INDEX idx_created_at_log_2023_12 asdf
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.log_2023_12" does not exist
Command was: CREATE INDEX idx_created_at_log_2023_12 ON public.log_2023_12 USING btree (created_at DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Sounds fair, because partitioned tables are created on INSERT by trigger, and looks like `pg_restore` is restoring with `COPY`. But then, how do I dump and restore partitioned table with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` into DB that did not create partitioned tables yet?

Comment: That makes no sense: `pg_restore` would create the partition tables first. Are you restoring with `--data-only`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've tried both with/without `--data-only` and no avail, error log in the body is ran without `--data-only`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ouch my mistake, I was specifying wrong DB (`postgres`). I was confused because restoring whole DB backup I should specify it rather than the backed up one to drop and recreate. But restoring only tables, it seems like I have to specify the actual DB it was in.

Comment: Well, is the partition table in the dump or not? What are the exact command lines you are using? What is the **first** error message?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Partition table is in the dump, but copying failed because the main table is not in `postgres`, but in the other DB. I fixed it by specifying the other DB (`--dbname`) and it works now. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: I fail to comprehend, but if you figured the problem out, all is good.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It helped me when I run pg_dump without `--table` parameter.
Try to use

```
pg_dump \
    --dbname "${DBNAME}" \
    --format "directory" \
    --file ./backup \
    --jobs "${JOBS}" \
    --username "${USERNAME}"
```